# Data unable to be inserted to SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to create an app that let user to input two int data type from a custom dialog and the data will be stored in SQLite. I used a Toast to see if the data is added correctly. The problem is that the data is not added correctly and I'm unable to identify the problem. According to the Logcat its says that it cannot find the database table

SCDDialog.java

```
public class SCDDialog extends AppCompatDialogFragment {
    private EditText et_plannedParticipation,et_totalParticipation;
    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getContext());
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_participation_dialog, null);

        builder.setView(view)
                .setTitle("Add Participation")
                .setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                    }
                })
                .setPositiveButton("confirm", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        insert();

                    }
                });
        et_plannedParticipation = view.findViewById(R.id.et_plannedParticipation);
        et_totalParticipation = view.findViewById(R.id.et_totalParticipation);
        return builder.create();
    }

    private void insert() {
        boolean result = databaseHelper.insertSCD(Integer.parseInt(et_plannedParticipation.getText().toString()),
                Integer.parseInt(et_totalParticipation.getText().toString()));
        if (result) {
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Data has been added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Please insert all the fields correctly", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

DatabaseHelper.java

```
    public boolean insertSCD(int scdPP, int scdTP) {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_SCD_PP, scdPP);
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_SCD_TP, scdTP);
        long insert = sqLiteDatabase.insert(SCD_TABLE, null, contentValues);
        if (insert == -1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Logcat

```
2022-01-15 00:55:10.307 6147-6147/com.example.test4 E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: SCD_TABLE in "INSERT INTO SCD_TABLE(SCD_PP,SCD_TP) VALUES (?,?)"
2022-01-15 00:55:10.308 6147-6147/com.example.test4 E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting SCD_PP=12 SCD_TP=1
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: SCD_TABLE (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT INTO SCD_TABLE(SCD_PP,SCD_TP) VALUES (?,?)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1045)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:652)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:590)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:61)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:33)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1699)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1570)
        at com.example.test4.DatabaseHelper.insertSCD(DatabaseHelper.java:38)
        at com.example.test4.SCDDialog.insert(SCDDialog.java:47)
        at com.example.test4.SCDDialog.access$000(SCDDialog.java:14)
        at com.example.test4.SCDDialog$1.onClick(SCDDialog.java:37)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:167)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
2022-01-15 00:55:10.331 6147-6169/com.example.test4 D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0xee09a830 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xc5148e90
```

Comment: I suggest using the debugger in Android Studio to find out what is going on.

Comment: I did and it says that it cannot find the database table.

Comment: First, uninstall the app from the device and rerun, or run in a clean device.

Comment: Logcat is a helpful tool to see error messages and other logging output. This is not the debugger that I mentioned in my first comment time. I still recommend that you learn how to use the debugger to step through your code and view variables while the app is running. For example, if you set a breakpoint in `DatabaseHelper .onCreate()`, you can verify whether or not it is called.